# Excel Chart, How to only show monthly/weekly/biweekly data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I currently combine weekly data with daily data for an excel chart.

[image]
[image]

How can I select my data so it is consistenly weekly? Or is there a chart feature to only include the weekly data? I don't want to manually pick dates either using the date picker chart feature.

Comment: For the weekly data, is it some sort of aggregate of the daily data, or do you just want a given day's data?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad no aggegrate, just a given days.

Comment: Try using a Pivot Chart, and then "Group" the date axis to your desired span.

Comment: No please dont make me use a PIVOT CHART! PLEASE! I will if I have no other choice.

Comment: As a work-around, just convert your data to a pivot table and reap the benefits of that.  But, chart the data as a regular line or xy/scatter chart.  If you create the chart first, then select the data through the dialog box, you won't have to worry about the pivot chart nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first column of data is in column `A`, make a helper column with the following formula in it:

```
=WEEKDAY(A1)
```

and populate down

Autofilter on the day of the week you want to use for your data.

The chart should skip hidden rows

Comment: if I converted to a pivot , would it be easier? I'm trying to incorporate this stuff in vba.